# how to set start page on hosting server after uploading the asp.net site

Tags: asp.net

i have uploaded my site on hosting server with name www.selectionfurnishing.com
but when i try to open any page i got an error that the site does not exits 
when i try www.selectionfurnishing.com/default.aspx then it gives error that the page does not exits (404)

please tell me how can i solve this ....
Thanks

Comment: You should probably check with your hosting vendor. Who's doing the hosting for you?

Answer (score 0):

You say it's hosted? I would suggest contacting your hosting provider. I would imagine it's a config issue on their side.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running IIS7, you should be able to set the start page for your site in your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```